# pygame: часть картинки не выводиться на экран

Tags: python, pygame

этот код должен на весь экран выводить изображение. В принципе он и выводит, но из-за неподходящего разрешения, картинка либо обрезается, либо экран начинает сжиматься под картинку (такое происходит если картинка 4:3, а у меня монитор 16:9).

вот сам код:

```
_PNG_IMAGE = 'pc1.png'
pygame.display.init()
img = pygame.image.load(_PNG_IMAGE)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(img.get_size(), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

надо сделать так, чтоб картинка была на весь экран, никак не обрезалась, и экран не сжимался в 4:3

Comment: Ну так приведите картинку к желаемому виду.

Comment: а если программа расчитана на многих людей а не только под себя, и у каждого разные мониторы?

Comment: @Александр а если программой буду пользоваться не только я? и у других людей будут другие мониторі

Comment: Можно узнать разрешение, потом изменить размер. Соотношение 4:3 в 16:9 я думаю невозможно будет сделать.

Comment: Добавьте картинку, которую используете.